# Ionic Bluetooth serial SubscribeRawData update UI

Tags: angular, bluetooth, arduino, ionic3

I am using this plugin https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial to manage bluetooth connection etc and I am using a HC-06 module on arduino Leonardo. Everything is working just fine the problem is on the mobile application. 
Here is the home.ts

```
connect() {
    this.blt = this.bluetoothSerial.connect("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX");
    this.blt.subscribe((data) => {
        this._disable1 = false;
        this._connected = true;

        this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe((dt) => {
            this.bluetoothSerial.read().then((dd) => {
                this.onDataReceive(dd)
            });
        });
    }, (error) => {
        this._connected = false;
        this.setStatus("Not Connected");
    });
}

sendToHc(num) {
    this.bluetoothSerial.write(""+num).then((ok) => { });
}

dummyCheck() {
    // Do nothing
}

onDataReceive(dd) {
    this._debug += "\n" + JSON.stringify(dd);

}
```

On the home.html there is a button that calls connect() and another that call sendToHc with a parameter. everything so far is ok. the issue is when subscribeRawData reads the response from arduino it doesn't update the UI automatically. I have to insert a 3rd button to call dummyCheck() and after that UI is updated. Is there anyway to update the UI automatically when reading the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the nested subscriptions are outside the Angular scope and when an update arrives change-detection is not run. When you press the dummy button a `click` event is fired which triggers change-detection and your updates become visible on the DOM. You can run change-detection manually using `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe((dt) => {
  this.bluetoothSerial.read().then((dd) => {
    this.onDataReceive(dd);
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // either here
   });
});

onDataReceive(dd) {
  this._debug += "\n" + JSON.stringify(dd);
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // or here
}
```

The docs regarding this can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). And [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) is a very nice article on the topic in general.

Answer (score 0):

---

I was in struggling in the same scenario and **cdr** also resolved my error. As **David** mentioned the problem is with the DOM not getting updated. Here is my code, if it helps you or anyone.

```
if(this.BLconnected == false) {
  this.shared.showLoading('Please wait. App is connecting to the Glove');
  this.connectToBT(); //Function to connect to the Bluetooth
}else {
//I set the delimiter as ';' because i print ';' at every print end in my arduino
  this.bluetoothSerial.subscribe(';').subscribe((data) => {
      this.spokenWord = data;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      console.log(data);
});
```